Is it sinful to differentiate between Lord Vishnu and Shiva?
I'm looking for scriptural evidence that one is to not differentiate between Lord Vishnu and Shiva.
Also, what is the consequence of differentiating them?
Kindly quote from the Puranas which glorify Lord Vishnu.

Yes, even as per the Puranas which glorify Lord Vishnu, one should never differentiate between Lord Vishnu and Lord Shiva.

A sign of avidya or ignorance:

Krishna says to Lord Shiva: That which I am, You are, and that also is this world, with its gods, demons, and mankind. Men contemplate distinctions being stupefied by ignorance ~ Vishnu Purana 5.33.48


Lord Brahma eternally salutes those who...
A person who looks upon the Lord of Gods Narayana and Shiva equally
without any discrimination is always saluted by Lord Brahma.~Narada
Purana 1.3.59


The result of distinguishing between Shiva and Vishnu:
Those who consider me (Lord Shiva) as different from Vishnu, are driven to
do sinful deeds and reach hell.~Varaha Purana 70.40


The wise beings should never distinguish between Lord Shiva and Vishnu:
I (Shiva) am Vishnu as well as Brahma the three gods are really one
and the wise should not differentiate between them. ~Varaha Purana
72.14


Lord Vishnu is the heart of Shiva and Lord Shiva is the heart of Vishnu:
śaivaṃ ca vaiṣṇavaṃ rūpamekarūpaṃ narottama dvayośca aṃtaraṃ nāsti
ekarūpamahātmanoḥ | śivāya viṣṇurūpāya śivarūpāya viṣṇave śivasya
hṛdayaṃ viṣṇurviṣṇośca hṛdayaṃ śivaḥ |
O king, the form of Śiva and that of Viṣṇu are identical. There is no
difference between the glorious two, who are of the same form. Salute
Śiva of the form of Viṣṇu, and Viṣṇu of the form of Śiva. Viṣṇu is the
heart of Śiva, and Śiva is the heart of Viṣṇu. ~Padma Purana
2.71.19–21


Vishnu is identical with Shiva:
Markandeya said: Shiva is identical with Vishnu and Vishnu is
identical with Shiva. I do not see any difference. They are both
auspicious, without beginning, middle or end, eternal and undecaying. ~Harivamsha 2.127.29


Hari and Hara are the Creator, Preserver and Destroyer of the
universe. I will now chant their glories. Vishnu is adorable unto
Rudra, and Rudra is adorable unto Vishnu. They are one, still they
range in the world under two forms. Vishnu is not different from
Shankara and Shankara is not different from Vishnu. Therefore,
formerly Rudra and Upendra became one. Salutation unto Rudra and
Krishna of one united body. Harivamsha 2.127.40-42

Source for more quotations from other Puranas.
